# How to check if function exist in Sybase, and if yes then drop

Tags: sybase

How to check if function exist in `Sybase`? And if yes then drop?

Like I can check for stored procedure:

```
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure Sp_Name    Script Date: 05/18/2015 16:33:46 ******/
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE NAME = 'Sp_Name' AND TYPE='P')
DROP PROCEDURE Sp_Name
GO
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do either of the following:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('my_function') IS NOT NULL
    DROP FUNCTION my_function
```

Or

```
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT  1
    FROM    sysobjects
    WHERE   NAME = 'my_function'
    AND     TYPE = 'SF'
)
    DROP FUNCTION my_function
GO
```

Thanks,
Meet